# Java application container

Tags: java, containers

What is the best way to run many Java console applications together in a container? It can be thought as a multi-threaded Java application exploded into many little Java applications. It would be great if the container could also monitor the state of the applications and restart when an applications fails, and monitor the performance if possible. Can OSGi help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already considered [MBeans](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html)?